# How to create a Shortcut on the Home Screen in Android 8?

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo

I will create shortcut on Home screen in android 8 and used `ShortcutManager` it's creating shortcut in Context Menu and user should manually drag shortcut on Home Screen while in lower Android 8 automatically created on Home Screen
my code is:

```
ShortcutManager sM = (ShortcutManager) getSystemService(SHORTCUT_SERVICE);


Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MasterActivity.class);
intent1.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);


ShortcutInfo shortcut1 = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, "shortcut1")
    .setIntent(intent1)
    .setLongLabel("Ayande")
    .setShortLabel("This is the Ayandeh")
    .setDisabledMessage("Login to open this")
    .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.ayandeh))
    .build();

sM.addDynamicShortcuts(Arrays.asList(shortcut1));
```

result:

[image]

but result I want create shortcut Automatically:

[image]

Comment: no idea for this?

Comment: Please check this:- https://forums.androidcentral.com/android-8-0-oreo/835904-add-home-screen-shortcut-not-working-documents-since-update.html

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Use ShortcutManager.requestPinShortcut. But be aware that that method will open a dialog asking the user whether to add the shortcut to the home screen or not. Unfortunately for me this dialog was opening behind other activities, and so was never visible!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This Method

```
private void createShortcut() {
    ShortcutManager shortcutManager = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
        shortcutManager = mContext.getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (shortcutManager != null) {
            if (shortcutManager.isRequestPinShortcutSupported()) {
                ShortcutInfo shortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(mContext, uniqueid)    
                        .setShortLabel("Demo")
                        .setLongLabel("Open the Android Document")
                        .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(mContext, R.drawable.andi))
                        .setIntent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("https://stackoverflow.com")))
                        .build();

                shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(shortcut, null);
            } else
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Pinned shortcuts are not supported!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```